# How to format Apex code more flexible than with Prettier

Tags: vs-code, formatting, source

> Note: This is a Salesforce-specific question so don't close it.
>   Salesforce has contributed a Prettier plugin for Apex so in other
>   forums people cannot help me.

I'm new to [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) and couldn't find out how to enforce the following rules in **Prettier**. Maybe a **Prettier** expert out there can help with a customized `.prettierrc` which has these rules:

1. Don't wrap method parameters as extra lines
2. Have 2 blank lines between each method
3. Have blank line before last return statement
4. Leave the first line of a method always blank
5. Leave the first line of a class always blank
6. Don't enforce line length. Don't break lines. Not in code and not in SOQL.
7. Don't put an extra space between if/else/while and the brace.
8. Catch statement in an extra line

**So instead of this:**

[image]

**I want this:**
[image]

*I also added a question here as Uncrustify might be the better tool to do this: https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues/2526*

Comment: What are your reasons for needing to fully control the formatting of Apex?  I assume it is a personal perference? I wrestled with this myself, as I was also not happy with some of the ways Prettier was formatting Apex code. However, I found that it was just easier to use Prettier as a defacto formatting standard. Now I no longer need to maintain a Coding Style Guide at work. Our team has been freed up from pointless discussions on style and formatting during code reviews. Also new team members get same formatted code as experienced team members all for free.

Comment: uncrustify which has [several answered posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=uncrustify) on SFSE can be used with Apex as well. It offers a different approach to formatting and formatting options than prettier.

Comment: From my understanding, uncrustify does not offically support Apex and you need to use the Java mode for formatting which doesn't always do the right thing, there are a [few reported issues](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+is%3Aclosed+apex+) but doesn't look like they are going to support. Prettier for Apex, has the advantage of using the  jorje compiler from Salesforce for parsing Apex and apparently has been tested on some of Salesforce's internal code bases.

Comment: @Robert Sösemann did you ever find a tool that that's more customizable? If not, would like to hear a bit about how this played out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prettier by design does not really allow customization of the formatting, this is why it is an "Opinionated Source Formatter".

For Apex, your formatting options are limited to the following configuration settings:

- `printWidth`
- `tabWidth`
- `useTab`

https://github.com/dangmai/prettier-plugin-apex

**Source to be formatted:**

```
public with sharing class Controller {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
        Process result;

        try {
            result = new ApplicationService().getProcesses(accountId, new Application.DisplayAttributes()
                                                                              .pageSize(pageSize)
                                                                              .filter(filter));
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

**Formatted with `printWidth` 80:**

```
$ prettier --print-width 80 --tab-width 4  Controller.cls
public with sharing class Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(
        Id accountId,
        Integer pageSize,
        String filter
    ) {
        Process result;

        try {
            result = new ApplicationService()
                .getProcesses(
                    accountId,
                    new Application.DisplayAttributes()
                        .pageSize(pageSize)
                        .filter(filter)
                );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

**Formatted with `printWidth` 100:**

```
$ prettier --print-width 100 --tab-width 4 Controller.cls
public with sharing class Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
        Process result;

        try {
            result = new ApplicationService()
                .getProcesses(
                    accountId,
                    new Application.DisplayAttributes().pageSize(pageSize).filter(filter)
                );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

**Formatted with `printWidth` 120:**

```
$ prettier --print-width 120 --tab-width 4 Controller.cls
public with sharing class Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
        Process result;

        try {
            result = new ApplicationService()
                .getProcesses(accountId, new Application.DisplayAttributes().pageSize(pageSize).filter(filter));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

I would recommend increasing the `printWidth` to 120 and forget about trying to control the formatting, just let Prettier do its thing :)

Alternatively, a change to the input source might produce more favorable output with regards to readablility and line length.

**Source to be formatted with display attributes as a temporary variable:**

```
public with sharing class Controller {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
        Process result;

        try {
            Application.DisplayAttributes attributes = new Application.DisplayAttributes()
                .pageSize(pageSize)
                .filter(filter);

            result = new ApplicationService().getProcesses(accountId, attributes);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

**Formatted with `printWidth` 100:**

```
$ prettier --print-width 100 --tab-width 4 Controller.cls
public with sharing class Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize, String filter) {
        Process result;

        try {
            Application.DisplayAttributes attributes = new Application.DisplayAttributes()
                .pageSize(pageSize)
                .filter(filter);

            result = new ApplicationService().getProcesses(accountId, attributes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new ApplicationException().throwAuraHandle(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Process getProcesses(Id accountId, Integer pageSize) {
        return getProcesses(accountId, pageSize, '*');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some significant frustration, I discovered that if you have a `.prettierrc.json` file defined in your repo, the VS Code Prettier settings will be ignored.  Therefore you will want your config file to look something like this for 120 width:

```json
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.html",
      "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    }
  ]
}
```